# Problem rearranging a trigonometric expression

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry

I've been trying to figure out why this equation is satisfied:

$$\frac{1-(\cos(x))^3}{x^2}=\frac{2\cdot(\sin(\frac{x}{2}))^2}{x^2}\cdot(1+\cos(x)+(\cos(x))^2)$$

but I can't find the proper trigonometric changes in order to change from one to another. I know that the sine comes from the double angle formula, but I obtain slightly different results in other parts and it's never the same as the formula above.

I'd appreciate any hint.

Thanks for the time.

Comment: The "double-angle" formula $2\sin^2(x/2)=1-\cos x$ almost finishes things.

Comment: @AndréNicolas What happens with the cubed cosine?

Comment: Then letting $t=\cos x$, we get that the top of the right-hand side is $(1-t)(1+t+t^2)$, which is $1-t^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may observe that, in general,
$$
a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)
$$ giving
$$
1-(\cos x)^3=(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x+(\cos x)^2)
$$ then, by using $2\sin^2(x/2)=1-\cos x$ as noticed by @André Nicolas, you are Ok with your expression.